# Data Binding set a static String as input

Tags: android, data-binding, callback, android-databinding

I'm using data binding in my application and and my call back interface for onclick

```
public interface HomeCallBack {
void onProvinceClick(String provinceName);
}
```

and inside of XML I need to set static string as province name
is that possible ?

```
 <ImageView
            android:onClick="@{(v)->callBack.onProvinceClick(static string)}"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_40"
            android:src="@drawable/broken_heart" />
```

Comment: where is your viemodel

Comment: I don't have any yet (this is test of my project)

Comment: provide your string like this: \`static string\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass like this

```
<ImageView
        android:onClick='@{(v)->callBack.onProvinceClick("Your text")}'
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_40"
        android:src="@drawable/broken_heart" />
```